# Bootstrap tabs containing different forms

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I have 2 bootstrap tabs in my html page, each containing different forms.
Form Action has been specified to the same jsp page.

When I am submitting a form from 2nd tab, the whole page is getting reloaded, and page sets 1st tab active as it is set by default.

What can I do to avoid this? When I submit form from 2nd tab, I want the same page but the second tab active as it should be.

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id=passengerTabs>
   <li role="presentation" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab"
    href="#searchbyflight">Search By Flight Number</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab"
    href="#searchbypassenger">Search By Customer Name</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
   <div class="container tab-pane fade in active" id="searchbyflight">
    <form class="form-inline" method="get" action="PassengerDetails.jsp">
     <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textFlightNumber"
       name="textFlightNumber">
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
      id="searchflightnumber">Search Customers</button>
    </form>
   </div>

   <div class="container tab-pane fade in" id="searchbypassenger">
    <form class="form-inline" method="get" action="">
     <div class="form-group">
      <input
       type="text" class="form-control" id="textCustomerName"
       name="textCustomerName">
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
      id="searchCustomerName">Search Customers</button>
    </form>
    <br>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You could redirect to your chosen page at end of insert script. But I guess the same would happen. Or use Ajax